# Getting Special character while creating a file

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, streamwriter

I am writing text to a file but getting special character appended at the beginning. Can anyone please guide why it is happening and how can we avoid it.

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    w.Write(@"
COMMENT: OnDemand Generic Index File Format
COMMENT: This file has been generated by DOC Application
COMMENT: date");
                 }
             }
```

When I open this file I am getting special character at the starting like:

> Â
>
> COMMENT: OnDemand Generic Index File Format COMMENT: This file has
> been generated by DOC Application
>
> COMMENT: date

Comment: Out of interest why a binarywriter not a textwriter?

Comment: have to try by removing space between @("  and COMMENT:

Comment: The code you posted has a different output. The leading character is `v` = `0x76` = `118` which is the length of the string that is written. This is the behaviour of `BinaryWriter`. *(And also there is `enter` before the second comment.)* Results can be different for Linux *(or when using only `LF`, not `CR+LF`)*.

Comment: To avoid that - don't use `BinaryWriter`. It's not intended for what you are trying to do. Use `StreamWriter` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`BinaryWriter` is intended for writing binary files when paired with `BinaryReader` - it implements a very simple protocol for a range of common types needed in simple serializers - for example strings are length prefixed. What you're seeing here as `Â` is: the length prefix.

Basically, don't use `BinaryWriter` to write text files. Either use `File.WriteAllText` (for a single string), or `File.CreateText` which will give you a `TextWriter` (specifically, a `StreamWriter`).

So:

```
File.WriteAllText(FILE_NAME, @"
COMMENT: OnDemand Generic Index File Format
COMMENT: This file has been generated by DOC Application
COMMENT: date");
```

or:

```
using(var file = File.CreateText(FILE_NAME))
{
    file.Write(...); // etc
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's an encoding problem, it used to happen to ALL my files to. After a little playing, here's the easiest way, get the bytes with an explicit encoding first, then BinaryWriter.Write won't need to wrongly-guess the encoding:

```
byte[] mybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"
COMMENT: OnDemand Generic Index File Format
COMMENT: This file has been generated by DOC Application
COMMENT: date");

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\2.txt", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        w.Write(mybytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's NOT an encoding problem. TextWriters and derived classes use UTF8 by default unless you specify a different encoding. *This* code is a bug waiting to happen though. If you enter any character outside the 7-bit ASCII range you'll get incorrect characters at best. Worst case, the characters that can't be mapped will be replaced by `?` and you'll lose data

Comment: BTW there's nothing to guess about encodings. .NET and *Windows* in general use Unicode, UTF16 specifically. The string you converted to ASCII was a UTF16 string.

Comment: Not to be rude, but does any of that help OP with their issue? <3

Comment: Yes. Don't use BinaryWriter. Don't use this code. Read Marc Gravell's answer to understand what you are doing wrong. Instead of fixing a (non-existent) problem you *added* one